# How do you switch between pnpm versions?

Tags: package-managers, pnpm

I'm currently working on an application that uses pnpm 6 but I have pnpm 7 installed. I couldn't find any documentation that shows me how to install and switch between versions. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

If you have installed pnpm through Node.js **corepack**:

```
corepack enable
```

you can just run:

```
corepack prepare pnpm@7.13.6 --activate
```

Here is the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html)

Answer (score 7):

I'm also going with **node.js/corepack**. I have to jump between versions 6 and 7 for different projects.

With a recent version of node.js (16.17+) it's even easier to switch between the most recent of major versions of pnpm. For the latest of version 7 you'd type:

```
corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate
```

For the latest of version 6:

```
corepack prepare pnpm@latest-6 --activate
```

It's also described in the [installation doc](https://pnpm.io/installation#using-corepack) of pnpm.

Comment: this script worked well to get the lastest of a specific version! great find! the installation doc doesn' describe it though..

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better way but I just uninstalled version 7 and installed version 6. I did this with yarn but you can do it with any method listed in the uninstall/install documentation. Just make sure you uninstall using the method you originally used to install it (npm, yarn, brew, etc.).

- [Uninstall Documentation](https://pnpm.io/uninstall)
- [Install Documentation](https://pnpm.io/installation)

**This is what I did:**

```
yarn global remove pnpm
yarn global add pnpm@6.32.1 (installed specific latest pnpm version)
```

Currently, it seems there is no solution similar to nvm. [Reference](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/discussions/4446)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, [to setup the nextauthjs local environment](https://github.com/nextauthjs/.github/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#setting-up-local-environment) on Ubuntu 22.04 I did the followings.

- I had previously installed pnpm using [a standalone script](https://pnpm.io/installation#on-posix-systems).
- To avoid collisions I [removed the pnpm CLI](https://pnpm.io/uninstall#removing-the-pnpm-cli).
- I made sure [nvm version is up to date](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script).
- I configured [current node engine of the nextauthjs](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/cca94bfe83db84282f41d0e843d19a5526c39e84/package.json#L50). `nvm use v18.12.0`
- I enabled [current packageManager version of the nextauthjs](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/cca94bfe83db84282f41d0e843d19a5526c39e84/package.json#L52) using [corepack](https://pnpm.io/installation#using-corepack) `corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@7.23.0 --activate` ( `corepack enable pnpm` is should be enough too).

Answer (score 2):

If you wish for a one-liner to use whichever pnpm version you want, use `npx`:

```bash
npx pnpm@<version> <command>
```

For example, I have pnpm 8 installed globally but want to contribute to a project that depends on pnpm 6. This is how I do it:

```bash
npx pnpm@6 install
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it

```js
// enable corepack
corepack enable
// switch pnpm 7 version
corepack prepare pnpm@7.33.6 --activate
// switch pnpm latest version
corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate
```

you can set bash alias

```bash
alias pnpm7='corepack prepare pnpm@7.33.6 --activate'
alias pnpmlatest='corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate'
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed pnpm with Vite in 2022 or 2023 on Windows.

I did the global installations but 'pnpm -v' always returned the old version:

> pnpm i -g pnpm
>
> pnpm i -g @pnpm/exe
>
> pnpm ls -g
>
> // @pnpm/exe 8.5.1
>
> // pnpm 8.5.1
>
> pnpm -v
>
> // 7.25.1

The 'pnpm -v' finally gave me 8.5.1 after running the following commands:

> corepack enable
>
> corepack prepare pnpm@8.5.1 --activate